# Stop dplyr splitting names in gather(...) %<% separate(...)

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I stop dplyr automagically splitting names when doing `gather` `separate`?

```
cost <- data.frame(Date = rep('1970-01-01', 3), 
                   Atr = runif(3), 
                   Atrb = runif(3), 
                   a_t = runif(3), 
                   b_t = runif(3), 
                   a_t = runif(3), 
                   b_t = runif(3), 
                   a_t = runif(3), 
                   b_t = runif(3))

names(cost) <- c('Date', 'Atr','Atrb','a_t','b_t','a_t','b_t','a_t','b_t')

# Now we reshape and see the problem
idx = 4:9 
names(cost)[idx] = paste0(names(cost)[idx], ".", c(sapply(LETTERS[1:3], rep, times = 2)) )

cost.long = cost %>%
    gather(key, value, -c(Date:Atrb)) %>%
    separate(key, into = c("Metric", "Group"))

cost.long
```

You'll note in the output the variable names have been split and there is now only one group `t`:

```
> cost.long
         Date       Atr      Atrb Metric Group     value
1  1970-01-01 0.3555041 0.9343369      a     t 0.9022378
2  1970-01-01 0.2812809 0.9770834      a     t 0.0204206
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `sep` argument in `separate`

```
cost.long <- cost %>%
              gather(key, value, -c(Date:Atrb)) %>%
              separate(key, into=c("Metric", "Group"), sep="_")
```